# How to start soapui.sh under linux in background?

Tags: command-line, soapui, soap-client

How to start `soapui.sh` under Linux in background?

I tried several variants like:

```
nohup ./soapui.sh < /dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null &

nohup ./soapui.sh & < /dev/null 2>&1 > /dev/null &
```

When I performed **exit** and back to server again I haven't already seen SoapUI is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
nohup ./soapui.sh &
```

Comment: It doesn't work, when session is off , soapui.sh is stopped

Comment: Are you saying this after trying it?

Comment: .It works actually . I supposed it should be seen through **ps -a** or **jobs** . When i launch **ps -ef|grep soap** I see a lot soapui.sh processes

Comment: @BilowYuriy, glad it helped.